# Create new file in a folder with Apps Script using Google Advanced Drive service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

There are four ways to create a new file:

- DocsList - Shown as **DocsList** in the Main List. Built in to Apps Script.
- DriveApp - Shown as **Drive** in the Main List. Built in to Apps Script.
- Drive API - Also shown as **Drive** in the Main List.  *Must be added* to Apps Script.
- DocumentApp - Shown as **Document** in the Main List. Built in, but only creates a document file.

They are all called **services**.  Drive API is called an **advanced service**.  So, which one should you use?  I don't know, it depends.  This question is about the **Drive API** Advanced Service.

I don't want to use 2 or 3 of the services to get the job done.  I'd like to just use one of them.  But to decide which one to use, I need to know the capabilities and options of all of them.  If the simplest and easiest one to use will do everything I want, then I'll use that.

If I can create a new file with Drive API, but then I need to use the DriveApp service to move the file I created with Drive API, to the folder I want it in, then using Drive API in that particular situation is pointless.

I can create a new file in my Google Drive from a Google Apps Script `.gs` code, but the file gets written to the main 'My Drive'.  I want to write the file directly to a sub-folder. My current code is:

```
var fileNameSetA = 'someFile.jpg';
var uploadedBlobA = an image uploaded with a file picker;

var fileTestDrive = {
  title: fileNameSetA,
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
};

fileTestDrive = Drive.Files.insert(fileTestDrive, uploadedBlobA);
```

Even though the code works, I have no idea why the syntax is the way it is, and I can't find documentation that tells me why.  I can find a list of properties:

The `title:` and `mimeType:` are Optional Properties as part of the `Request Body`.  From the example, the Optional Properties are obviously put in a key:value paired object.  So, is the syntax:

```
Drive.Files.insert(optional properties, content);
```

There are also Required query parameters of:

`uploadType` --> `media`, `multipart`, `resumable`

But I don't see any required `uploadType` parameter designated anywhere in the example code.  So, I don't understand Google's documentation.

[Google Documentation Insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

Is it possible to write directly to a specific drive with Google Advanced Drive service in a Apps Script .gs code file?  How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for **INSERT** for the **Drive API** is found at this link:

[Drive API for INSERT](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

There is a section for **Request body**.  One of the **Optional Properties** for **Insert** is **parents[]**.  The brackets [] indicate that a list of parents can be designated.  The documentation for **parents[]** states this:

> Collection of parent folders which contain this file. Setting this
>   field will put the file in all of the provided folders. On insert, if
>   no folders are provided, the file will be placed in the default root
>   folder.

So, . . . using **Insert** in **Drive API**, . . . . *CAN* write a new file directly to a subfolder.  It's possible.

Now, the nomenclature and syntax for the **Google Drive SDK**, **HTTP request** is different than what is inside of Apps Script.

The syntax for invoking the Drive API HTTP Request inside of a `.gs` file is one of the following three:

- Drive.Files.insert(FILE resource)
- Drive.Files.insert(FILE resource, BLOB mediaData)
- Drive.Files.insert(FILE resource, BLOB mediaData, OBJECT optionalArgs)

The syntax shown in the list above is from the auto-complete drop down list inside the Apps Script code editor.  If you type `Drive.Files.` a list of possible methods will appear.  I can't find information about the syntax anywhere in the online documentation.

So, where does the **parents[]** optional property go?  Well, it's not a Blob, so we can rule that out.  It's either `FILE resource`, or `OBJECT optionalArgs`.  **optionalArgs** indicates that it's an **object**, but `FILE resource` is actually also an **object**.

In the examples, the `FILE resource` is constructed as key:value pair object.

[Uploading Files - Advanced Drive Service - Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#uploading_files)

Comment: FYI, there is a section in our documentation that describes how to map from a Google API's reference documentation to the equivalent advanced service in Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined

Comment: The key is the `parents[]` property which is a list of objects of form `{id: '...'}` where `id` is the unique ID of the parent folder in which you want to insert the document. You can obtain this ID by the usual listing of files.

Comment: This is better than Google's Documentation on the same function in GAS.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to create a new file is to use `DriveApp` which comes with pure Google Apps Script:

```
var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById("{dir_id}");
var file = dir.createFile(name, content);
```

If you do not know exact directory's id you can get the folder by its name:

```
var dir = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name).next();
```

The `next()` is there because `getFoldersByName()` returns collection of all directories whose names match given value.

Also check `DriveApp` docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Comment: Thanks.  I up-voted, but I can't mark it as correct answer.  I'm looking for a definitive answer to what is possible or not possible for Drive API when creating a file.

Comment: My understanding is that DriveApp cannot be used to add files to a shared drive. You must use Drive in that instance.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this is a bit late, but by looking at the [REST API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/folder), it shows that you can use Drive.Files.insert to insert into any folder. You simply have to add the folder's ID in the properties of the file you are inserting as such:

```
var file = {
   title: 'myFile',
   "parents": [{'id':folder.getId()}],  //<--By setting this parent ID to the folder's ID, it creates this file in the correct folder.
   mimeType: 'image/png'
 };
```

Folder ID can be obtained from the shareable link using the Google Drive GUI or as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list). (e.g. Use the Execute function on the right.)

Alternatively, you can access the folder by name by replacing the `folder.getID()` with [`Drive.getFoldersByName('name of folder')`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFoldersByName(String)).

This is helpful because `Drive.Files.insert()` accepts arguments while `Drive.createFile()` and `Drive.createFolder()` do not.

Answer (score 1):

## Direct Answer to Question

This summary from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive sums things up pretty well:

> The advanced Drive service allows you to use the Google Drive web API
>   in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's built-in Drive service, this
>   API allows scripts to create, find, and modify files and folders in
>   Google Drive. In most cases, the **built-in service is easier to
>   use**, but this **advanced service provides a few extra features**,
>   including access to custom file properties as well as revisions for
>   files and folders.
>
> Like all advanced services in Apps Script, **the advanced Drive
>   service uses the same objects, methods, and parameters as the public
>   API**.

Essentially `DriveApp` is easier to use than `Drive`, but `Drive` gives you more functionality since it shares the same functionality of the public API. I was not able to see how to save a file to a Shared/Team drive using `DriveApp`, so I ended up using `Drive`. The pain came around lack of documentation for the Google Apps Script implementation of `Drive`.

## Explanation of My Solution and Code Sample:

A specific implementation of saving a file to Google drive, but this will likely be useful for others. It took me a whole day to figure this out since the documentation and code examples for Google Apps scripts is severely lacking. My use case was for saving a JSON file to a shared Google Drive (Team Drive).

There are three parameters that I did not have at first and my files were not uploading. I am not sure if all are necessary. One was the `"kind": "drive#parentReference"` part of the `parents` metadata. The next was `"teamDriveId": teamDriveId` which is also in the metadata. The last parameter was `"supportsAllDrives": true` which I passed in the optional parameter location of `Drive.Files.insert()`.

I found the API explorer on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert to be very useful in figuring out which parameters were needed and how they needed to be formatted. I basically edited values in the explorer till I got a network request that worked. I then pulled the parameters I used into my Google Apps script.

```
/**
 *  Creates a JSON file in the designated Google Drive location
 *  @param {String} jsonString - A JS string from the result of a JSON.stringify(jsObject)
 *  @param {String} filename - The filename. Be sure to include the .json extension
 *  @param {String} folderId - The ID of the Google Drive folder where the file will be created
 *  @param {String} teamDriveId - The ID of the team drive
 *  @return {void}
 */
function createJSONFileInDriveFolder(jsonString, filename, folderId, teamDriveId) {
  var metadata = {
    "title": filename,
    "mimeType": "application/json",
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": folderId,
        "kind": "drive#parentReference"
      }
    ],
    "teamDriveId": teamDriveId
  };
  var optionalParams = {
    "supportsAllDrives": true
  };

  try {
    var jsonBlob = Utilities.newBlob(jsonString, 'application/vnd.google-apps.script+json');
    Drive.Files.insert(metadata, jsonBlob, optionalParams);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var searchthreads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox AND after:2020/11/30 AND has:attachment');//"in:all -in:trash category:social older_than:15d
   Logger.log("GMAIL thread 0:"+ searchthreads[0].getId());
   Logger.log("GMAIL thread 1:"+ searchthreads[1].getId());
   Logger.log("GMAIL thread 2:"+ searchthreads[2].getId());
   Logger.log("Active User: " + me);
   Logger.log("Search Thread: " + searchthreads.length);
   Logger.log("Gmail lenght" + gmailthread.length);
   //Logger.log("Gmail lenght" + gmailMessages.length);
   for (var i in searchthreads){
   
   var messageCOunt = searchthreads[i].getMessageCount();
   Logger.log("messageCOunt :"  + messageCOunt);
   var messages =  searchthreads[i].getMessages();
   for (var m in messages){
       var messagesender = messages[m].getFrom();
       var messageDate = messages[m].getDate();
       var messageReplyTo = messages[m].getReplyTo();
       var messagesubject = messages[m].getSubject();
       var messagebody = messages[m].getSubject();
       var messagephoneNo = messages[m].getSubject();
       //messages[m].isInInbox();
       var messageid = messages[m].getId();
       var messageplainbody = messages[m].getSubject();//messages[0].getPlainBody();  
       var EmailStatus ='N';
       var ApptStatus = "CVReceived";// Tracking till candidate offer and payout
       var messageattachement = messages[m].getAttachments();
     //var png=UrlFetchApp.fetch(messageattachement).getBlob();
     //https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RY4i6FwUvfy5OxrJ1pZTxJAOxjFFXbhz?usp=sharing
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1RY4i6FwUvfy5OxrJ1pZTxJAOxjFFXbhz");
    // DriveApp.getFolderById("1RY4i6FwUvfy5OxrJ1pZTxJAOxjFFXbhz").createFile(png);
     //DriveApp.createFile();
     
     for (var k in messageattachement){
       var filename = messageattachement[k].getName(); 
       var filesize = messageattachement[k].getSize();
       var filecontent = messageattachement[k].getContentType();
       var fileBlob = messageattachement[k].getAs(filecontent);
       var filecpblob = messageattachement[k].copyBlob();
       //folder.createFile(filename, messageattachement);
      
       
    
      var file = {
    title: filename,
    "parents": [{'id':folder.getId()}],
    mimeType: filecontent
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, filecpblob);
         
  //DataStudioApp  
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);
       //folder.createFile(filecpblob);
      }
       var processeddate = new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this question was posted. But here is the solution to help other readers. When using `Drive.Files.insert()` method, in order to specify a location for the inserted file, you must specify the `parents[]` property within the `FILE resource`. So expanding on @Alan Wells response here is the syntax for writing a blob as Goggle Spreadsheet format in a specific folder.

```
let newFile = {title: 'Title goes here', parents: [{id: targetFolderId}]};
let savedFile = Drive.Files.insert(
                  newFile,
                  blobGoesHere,
                  {mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, convert: true});
```

Please note that `parents:` takes an array of objects. You can specify multiple locations for a single file (it will be created in all the specified folders). Even if you want to use a single location you still have to provide this object in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the DriveApp to create a file in a specified folder this way.

```
var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderByName("MyDriveFolder");
var file = driveFolder.createFile(formObject.txtReceipt);
file.setName("MyFile");
```

PS: formObject.txtReceipt is coming from a file upload control on a form in the html and this returns a blob