# Create a new folder in Drive using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is there a way to create a google app script to create a new folder in Google Drive that is NOT IN THE ROOT FOLDER? A script to move a folder in the root to a particular folder will also do.

Comment: search this forum as it has been asked answered before

Comment: You should google for answers before asking. Here's the duplicate: [GAS-create-folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225398/create-new-file-in-a-folder-with-apps-script-using-google-advanced-drive-service)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new file in a folder with Apps Script using Google Advanced Drive service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225398/create-new-file-in-a-folder-with-apps-script-using-google-advanced-drive-service)

Comment: look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910734/google-apps-script-how-do-i-create-a-file-in-a-folder/30720190#30720190

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder("My New Folder Name");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId());
  var newFolder=parentFolder.createFolder("name folder")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to need the folder ID to let's say move or create a file there you can do the following.

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
var newFolderID = parentFolder.createFolder("New Folder Name").getId();
```

Then you can do this

```
DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The  folder object has a `createFolder` method, see [doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFolder(String)).
so you should simply get the folder you want and create the new one from there.

Answer (score 0):

`getFolderById` seems to be removed.

Try this:

```
function createFolder(parentFolderName)
{
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var folder = folders.next();
   if(parentFolderName == folder.getName())
     folder.createFolder("Folder Name");
 }
}
```