# how to Create a folder if it does not exist?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a script to add a folder on all subfolders if the folder is not existing. But unfortunately, I am generating only on one folder. How to make this changes under a parentfolder? Thank you for your answers.

Here is my code:

```
function folder_create(){

var foldername = 'CHECK FOLDS';
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
var foldersnext = folders.next();
var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();

var subfolders = subfolders.next();
var files = subfolders.searchFolders("title contains 'Testing Test'");
{
while(files.hasNext()){
var reportFolderExist = files.next();
var yearFolders = reportFolderExist.getFoldersByName("TESTTT");
if(yearFolders.hasNext()){
   
} else {
    reportFolderExist.createFolder("testing only----");
    
}
}  

}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a new folder in Drive using Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648174/create-a-new-folder-in-drive-using-google-app-script)

Answer (score 0):

#### Current situation:

If I understand you correctly, this is your current situation:

- You have a main folder called `CHECK FOLDS`.
- This main folder contains several subfolders.
- For each of these subfolders, you want to check whether they contain a folder whose `title` contains `Testing Test`.
- If the subfolder doesn't contain a `Testing Test` folder, create it.

#### Issue and solution:

If this is correct, the main issue in your code is that you are not iterating through all subfolders, but only accessing the first one `var subfolders = subfolders.next();`. You should use a loop instead, in order to check each subfolder (see code sample below).

Also, your code contains some confusing parts, like iterating through `files` (that is `Testing Test` folders) and looking for folders called `TESTTT` inside of these `files`. I don't think this makes sense, if the current situation is the one I described above.

#### Code sample:

```
function folder_create(){
  var foldername = 'CHECK FOLDS';
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var foldersnext = folders.next(); // Main folder
  var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) { // Loop through subfolders
    var subfolder = subfolders.next(); // Subfolder
    var files = subfolder.searchFolders("title contains 'Testing Test'");
    if (!files.hasNext()) { // Check if "Testing Test" exists.
      subfolder.createFolder("Testing Test"); // Create "Testing Test" folder inside subfolder
    }
  }
}
```